# Django: In memory database django.db.backends.sqlite3 + SessionMiddleware?

Tags: python, django, authentication, middleware

I'm using django 1.10.5 with py34.

I would like to configure the database such that everything happens in memory:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': ':memory:',
}
```

I also want to overwrite the user authentication as explain [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/) because the login and password must be loaded from my own conf.ini file.

After doing the modification, I get the error:

```
OperationalError at /
no such table: django_session 
During handling of the above exception ('SessionStore' object has no attribute '_session_cache'), another exception occurred:
```

Is it impossible to use the middleware django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware with an in memory database ?

Comment: What is the reason for wanting everything "in memory"?

Comment: I don't want a file sqlite nor a database to deploy on production. I prefer having all my configuration in an conf.ini file.

Comment: You *could* fix this particular issue by using a different session backend (eg the file or cookie backends), but as hop points out there are many other reasons this can't work. Use a proper database.

Comment: @debzsud what does "configuration in an conf.ini file" have to do with the database? also, "i don't want to" is not a reason… _why_ do you not want to?

Comment: Cool down bro. The only use I do of the database is storing one single user. Django forces you to link any user with a database, except if you override the whole system. The reason why I want the user credentials to be defined in the con.ini file is that my other projects work the same and use the same deployment script (I don't want to .gitignore extra files such as a sqlite database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An in-memory database is destroyed as soon as the process that created it exits. You can check this easily by executing `./manage.py migrate` and `./manage.py showmigrations` in succession: no migrations are recorded.

In short: this cannot work.

Comment: Then I must have a sqlite file somewhere ? What other option would you suggest ?